# Unnecessary precision displayed for flag weight

Tags: support, flag-weight

I currently have a flag weight of 531.7108. Is it just me, or are the 4 digits of precision after the decimal point just a tad unnecessary? Borderline bug I think.

Comment: The meta echo chamber is still alive and well, I see. This is why I normally don't bother posting here.

Comment: Yes, because if people disagree with you, there's gotta be something wrong with them.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta consider it an observation of how meta works since I joined SO.

Comment: Bug to some, feature to others.  You assert it is unnecessary.  I'm curious though - what harm is there in displaying it?  The status quo should remain unless and until there is good reason to change it.  I don't believe you've given good reason, or demonstrated the harm it causes to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 16):

Below 500 flag weight, flag increments are much larger, so we only show an integer.

Once you reach 500 flag weight or higher, flag increments will raise fractionally toward 750, so we show a double.

<s>It is possible for your flag weight to increase by .001 once you start approaching the maximum of 750.</s>

It was actually *intended* to behave this way, but the actual implementation is such that the [increase is always at least 0.1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569) for flags on questions and answers.

Comment: I think it can't be true what you're writing here; see [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101701/round-flag-weight-after-500/101704#101704) and [this answer by marcog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569). The truth seems to be an increase of 0.1 close to 750, for which one decimal digit would be quite sufficient.

Comment: Also [this answer by Wladimir Palant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-many-flags-to-reach-750-flag-weight/103161#103161) indicates that an increase by 0.001 is impossible.

Comment: I never said my maths were good! Quite the opposite, in fact...

Comment: I know - so shall I edit your answer to make it more correct?

Comment: do you have to even ask??

Comment: If flag weight is going to stay the same, I'd also vote for it to be dropped down to a single decimal digit. Also, if you have it always display that way, people won't ask "OH MY GOD WHY IS IT NOW A FLOAT" when they hit 510.0.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed the same thing, but I think there's a good reason. As the flag weight asymptotically approaches the limit (750 at the moment), each increment will be smaller and smaller, to the point where you might need 7 significant figures to see it change. Of course, you could get away with having fewer sigfigs for lower values, but that might be making it excessively complicated. Just having a consistent 4 decimals would handle nearly every case, even if it's sometimes ugly.

Comment: Do you really need to keep track of a fractional change in flag weight, 4 sig figs or not?

Comment: @Mark: Are you asking if *I* need to keep track, or if SO needs to keep track?

Comment: This is exactly my point; track it all you like, but 4 sig figs after the decimal is pointless for *display*.

Comment: @Shaggy: How can I track it if it's not displayed?

Comment: @Gabe Why do you *require* that level of precision to "track" the value? Rounding to the nearest integer value makes it much easier to read (as any fractional component is irrelevant to, at my guess, 99.99999% of users)

Comment: @Shaggy: At 531 you don't need 4 decimals, but at 749 you do. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Gabe why would anyone need 4 decimals, in general? This is still a bare assertion.

Comment: @Shaggy: Do you know what it means to asymptotically approach a limit? As your flag weight gets higher and higher, it increments by smaller and smaller amounts. At some point, the only way to tell that your flag weight has changed is that it will have gone up or down by 0.0001.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - If the value is bounded by a true asymptote, and it always increases, then you are guaranteed to eventually reach the level where you need 4 decimal digits of precision, where the next increment for a successful flag will push you from 749.9990 to 749.9991 (for example). Of course, this will eventually become insufficient for display as well (when you reach 749.9999). Presumably the developers think this will take an unfeasible amount of time to reach.

Comment: @Gabe @ire_and_curses You two are missing the point. I am not arguing the value shouldn't be stored as a floating point. Nor am I misunderstanding limits. My point is, to most users, showing fractional amounts of flag weight -- especially with 0.0001 precision -- is unnecessary. In what *reasonable* situation would a *user* absolutely *need* to know that degree of precision? e.g. when you look up current weather conditions, do you ever see that degree of precision?

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - Isn't it obvious? In the situation where you have extremely high flag weight, and would like to note that your flag weight has increased. What's the point of a display that doesn't tell you whether your score is changing? Weather is not a good analogy here, because weather does not have asymptotically more interesting precision (although temperature does, if you're a condensed matter physicist!). In other words, there is a characteristic scale for weather. There is no such scale for flag weight, because of its definition.

Comment: @ire_and_curses So we should optimize the display for the handful out of thousands of users that are obsessive-compulsive about fractional amounts of their flag weight?

Comment: @Shaggy Frog - Obsessive-compulsive? I really don't follow. There is no conceptual difference, after a successful flagging, between Alice being interested to see her flag weight moving from 150 to 160, and Bob noting that his flag weight has moved from 749.9990 to 749.9991. Exactly the same information has been conveyed. Why is Bob less entitled to that information than Alice?

Comment: @Shaggy: How about you just tell us how many decimals should be shown.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Bob should go outside and breathe in the fresh air @Gabe 0

Comment: @Shaggy - we're not optimizing for anyone, we're showing information *where it's relevant*.  Below 500 it's not relevant, so it's hidden.  Above 500, it *is* relevant (how else do you know it's changing **unless you can see it**?)

Comment: @Shaggy: If you think 0 decimals should be shown, then you think that only the 3 most significant digits should be displayed. Since your SO rep is currently 11068, why aren't you complaining about all those unnecessary digits? Surely you'd rather just see 11k or 11.1k on your profile page. Or are you so obsessive about your rep that you need to be able to track every point?

Comment: @Gabe You're making my point, because that's normally how it's shown on questions.

Comment: @Shaggy: I'm talking about your *profile* page. Do you want to be able to see all 5 (or 6 for people like John Skeet) digits of your rep on your profile page? Or is that only necessary for a handful of obsessive-compulsive people who should spend more time outside instead of contributing to SO?

Comment: @Nick: Above 500 it is relavant, indeed, but I think it would be nicer to first show only one additional digit, then two, then three, then four. An idea: If the last increase in flag weight was less than 10, show 1, for less than 1 show 2, for less than 0.1 show 3, for less than 0.01 show 4. (Sound reasonable to me as a mathematician.)

Comment: @Nick: One digit would suffice, and more than 2 digits can't be relevant since the increase [is always at least 0.1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569).

Answer (score 6):

No it's not a bug. You should read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight). And here is a quote that describe reason why we have those 4 digits:

> flag weight now goes to 750; deputy
>   badge still 500; **above 500, growth
>   is sub-linear**

Comment: This is not about *tracking the value*, it's about *how the value is displayed*.

Comment: I will consider it was -1 to my midnight English

Comment: @Shaggy - how do you see that something's changed if you can.... **see** it?