# Too many decimal places in flag weight display?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unnecessary precision displayed for flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83657/unnecessary-precision-displayed-for-flag-weight)

So, flag weight now asymptotically increase over 500, fine. But, the remaining question is: **why would it need to be displayed to four decimal places?**

> [image: snapshot]

Comment: You get even more decimal places if you hover over it. ♪

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is that as you get closer and closer to 750 the extra decimal places will become more and more relevant as the increments per flag get smaller and smaller.

Comment: My puny flag weight has zero decimal places, which fits with your statement.

Comment: Let me repeat here what I wrote to Nick Craver at [that other post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83657/155585): Above 500 it is relavant, indeed, but I think it would be nicer to first show only one additional digit, then two, then three, then four. An idea: If the last increase in flag weight was less than 10, show 1, for less than 1 show 2, for less than 0.1 show 3, for less than 0.01 show 4. (Sound reasonable to me as a mathematician.)

Comment: @Hend, that sounds reasonable to me as well.