# Repercussions when a flag gets declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I was wondering since i flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697102/nsurl-initialization-from-nsstring) for being low quality and got this response:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Does declined flags cause any form of repercussion?

Comment: A few declined flags here and there has no effect. Only worry if you get lots

Comment: **+1** I can't find a duplicate for this. *How* has it not been asked before?!

Comment: I wonder why the question has been removed then, if the flag was declined?

Comment: @skuntsel Sometimes the *flag itself* was not valid, but the post still needs to be removed.

Comment: I managed to find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119710/167646), but I couldn't immediately find an FAQ item.

Comment: @skuntsel Although in this instance, it was auto-deleted by Community ♦

Comment: The flagging system was updated recently, here's how it currently works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/162704 You'll find the answer to your question there, but it really should be posted as an answer here, so everyone can find it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count

Comment: @AlEverett ish, all the answers to that question are now wrong however as the system has changed

Comment: @AndrewBarber Probably there should also be a way to be able to put the question/answer in the low quality post queue, bypassing the moderators. As you told, flag for moderator's attention is invalid, but placement in the review queue could be.

Comment: @skuntsel You can flag a post as "very low quality" to put it in the "very low quality" post review queue.  Note that just because it's in the queue doesn't mean a moderator *won't* review it, just that someone besides a moderator *can* review it.

Comment: @Servy Really? I didn't know that. I know mods see those flags, but I didn't know they go to the review queue, too. Hmmm!

Comment: @AndrewBarber [Well, that's what Shog9 said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196616/still-having-issues-with-link-only-answer-flags/196628#comment621323_196628) just a few days ago.

Comment: @Servy Cool; thanks for the link! That might explain why mods don't get totally overwhelmed with these flags, and why we often see those flags accompanied by other flags, too.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - VLQ goes to the queue. Mods only see old ones that have not been resolved.