# Decimal Precision of Reputation Display

Tags: discussion

Can we have consistent precision in the display of reputation?

For example, if one has 9991 rep, and then receives 10 more, he has 10k rep. The precision goes from 4 digits to 1 digit. Then at some point the rep goes to 10.1k, which is three digits precision.

As computer scientists, we can do better!

Comment: but is it important at all? If you really want to know - click on it

Comment: I hope for you, Jeff doesn't have a giant decimal separator at home.

Comment: Not precise enough ... [too precise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83657/unnecessary-precision-displayed-for-flag-weight)... you can never win!

Comment: I think it should be replaced with colors so that the illiterate can understand. Or maybe even a speaker icon you can click on to hear their reputation. Perhaps the simplest would be: "MORE THAN YOU" and "LESS THAN YOU", since, let's be honest that's all we care about.

Comment: Is the time-resolution of minutes e.g. `asked 39 mins ago` a sore sight for you as well?

Comment: Jeez, I don't really like this idea either, but you don't have to sneer at the OP for asking.

Answer (score 11):

Hover over the value, precision you will see.

Comment: Ah, yoda you are